# Costs of making an app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

how many would you ask for an app for a big enterprise?

Comment: Show `myFragmentPagerAdapter`, please

Comment: Also, try to create a [mcve]. Does this happen with all Fragments of the ViewPager, or can you take some out while you debug?

Comment: i have 3 Fragments in my ViewPager, only the infoFragment doesn't want to go to the activity , but i tried another acitvity and it works , so the fault must be in infoactivity .. where i use a tablayout

Answer (score 2):

> have 3 Fragments in my ViewPager

Then why are you only getting two and the other is null?

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            new OnthaalFragment();
        case 1:
            new EventFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

That number is determined by this, by the way

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.mTabTitles.length;
}
```

Comment: no the fragmentpageradapter is for my tablayout on the infoactivity this has 2 tabs.

Comment: but i have indeed 3 fragments on my viewpager , so my application starts with viewpager with 3 fragments and one fragment can't go to another activity thats called infoactivity. on that activity i have tablayout connected with this fragmentpageradapter. you understand?

Comment: I'm saying that you should remove the `return null`, or return a fragment for position 2

Comment: oke i set 'return' befor the other cases and indeed it haves me a new error. again a null pointer exception. can you help me again?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.vives.degavers, PID: 6115
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.vives.degavers.adapter.EventAdapter com.vives.degavers.info.cedric.EventFragment$OnFragmentInteractionListener.getEventAdapter()' on a null object reference
                      at com.vives.degavers.info.cedric.EventFragment.onCreateView(EventFragment.java:40)

Comment: You should set a return before the other cases, you just needed to add another case, or remove the `default` case. Regarding the error. Yes it's different, but unrelated to your initial question. Your Activity is null at `EventFragment.onCreateView(Ev‌entFragment.java:40)`. That's all I can tell you. I can't see `EventFragment` in your question

Comment: You should post another question. That's an unrelated error. You never assigned `mListener` and so you cannot get the adapter from it. It's null. That's all I'll point out.